# Proof of convex set multiplied by a constant

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, optimization

I need two proofs:

Let's say S is a convex set:

```
λx + (1-λ)y ∈ S for every x,y∈S and λ∈[0, 1]
```

I need to show that cS where c is a constant in R is also a convex set:

```
λx + (1-λ)y ∈ 3S for every x,y∈cS and λ∈[0, 1]
```

---

second,
Let's say S is a convex set:

```
λx + (1-λ)y ∈ S for every x,y∈S and λ∈[0, 1]
```

T is also a convex set:

```
λx + (1-λ)y ∈ T for every x,y∈T and λ∈[0, 1]
```

Then I need to show that S+T is also a convex set:

```
λx + (1-λ)y ∈ S+T for every x,y∈S+T and λ∈[0, 1]
```

how do I prove this?

Also,

Comment: For the first question, I have:
λx + (1-λ)y ∈ S for every x,y∈S and λ∈[0, 1] and S<= cS,
therefore: λx + (1-λ)y ∈ cS for every x,y∈cS and λ∈[0, 1].

but i dont know if this is a good/appropriate answer

Comment: For the first problem begin with two points in the set $cS$ and show that they satisfy the relation you are given for defining a convex set. Specifically these points will be $cx$ and $cy$ and you'll need to show that the entire line between them is in $cS$.

For the second you begin with two points in $S+T$ and then use the convexity of $S$ and $T$ to show that the line between them is in $S+T$. Watch your notation closely here.

If you are still struggling try setting $a=\lambda, b=(1-\lambda)$ and working it that way. It may be easier to see what's happening from that perspective.

Comment: CyclotomicField, thank you. So for the first problem, can I just multiply the whole thing by c and have something like this: c * λx + (1-λ)y ∈ S is λcx + (1-λ)cy ∈ cS? Would that be enough to prove this?

Comment: The other way around. Begin with $\lambda cx + (1- \lambda) cy$ manipulate it into the first expression. From there you can conclude that $c[\lambda x + (1- \lambda) y)] \in cS$ because it's $c$ times some point in $S$. This is where you use the convexity of $S$, The addition problem works similarly.

Comment: CyclotomicField, How do i mantipulate it into the first expression? Do I just divide the whole thing by c?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a worked example of the first proof. Let $S$ be a convex set, $c \in \mathbb{R}$ a constant, and $cS := \{cs \mid s \in S\}$. We would like to show that $cS$ is convex, that is, for any $x, y \in cS$ and $\lambda \in [0, 1]$ that the point $\lambda x + (1 - \lambda)y$ lies in $cS$.

Take any $x, y \in cS$ and $\lambda \in [0, 1]$. By definition of $cS$, there exist points $a, b \in S$ such that $x = ca$ and $y = cb$. Since $S$ is convex, we know that $\lambda a + (1 - \lambda)b$ lies in $S$, that is, $\lambda a + (1 - \lambda)b = s$ for some $s \in S$. Multiplying the equation by $c$, we have $\lambda c a + (1 - \lambda) c b = cs$, which is the same as $\lambda x + (1 - \lambda)y = cs$ for some $s \in S$. Hence, by definition of $cS$, $\lambda x + (1 - \lambda)y$ lies in $cS$.

Can you do the second proof in a similar way?